# (C#) Convert PDF to page-by-page JPEGs (needed for a dynamic page flip engine)

Tags: c#, pdf, jpeg

I need to convert a pdf file to a jpeg page-by-page images.
The reason I need to do this is, I'm creating a dynamic page flip on a asp.net website. I'm currently using [MegaZine](http://www.megazine3.de/?c=support&l=en) pageflip engine, wich loads jpeg files and makes a flip book. All I need to do now, is convert the pdf file to a bunch of jpegs, so that when the user clicks "upload pdf and make pageflip", the code behind does all the work.

So is there a (**free**) library I can use to do this?

I've been googleing for some time, but could not find anything good. Maybe you guys know something.

Thanks for the anwser in advance!!!

Andrej

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711942/convert-pdf-file-to-jpg-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [MagickNet](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#dot-net)? It's the .NET interface to ImageMagick, which is the go-to lib for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using either PDF2Image, PDF2Cairo or MUPDF to do this. Here's a link to PDF2Image:

http://code.google.com/p/pdf2image